# Translating Data from English to marathi in asp.net reports

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to convert the data of the report from English to Marathi.But I have to save the data into english format in sql db.
How can I convert the data using c# code or is there any other possible way without using third party translators...

Comment: see if https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest helps

Comment: @shreesha but the data would be keeping on changes as per the users.So how would I use resource files??? I tried it once but didn't get the output..

Comment: then you have to use third party translators.you can use resource files only when the data is static